# Play torrented video while downloading in uTorrent

Tags: data-transfer, streaming, torrent

I've seen this feature is available in uTorrent 3.0, but the mac version is only 1.8.7? How do I play torrents while they download on OS X?

Comment: Try Popcorn Time or ISOPlex. http://isoplex.isohunt.to/?lang=en&refname=&refurl=

Comment: I'm not doing this as an illegal thing. I own the videos I'm torrenting, I'm just trying to figure out how to grab a few frames without downloading the whole blasted thing

Answer (score 1):

Given the way torrents work ( piece from here, piece from there ) wether you can play a part before downloading the whole will depend on wether you have the part you want.

In short, maybe yes, maybe no.

Comment: That's correct but is it possible to do that with uTorrent v. 1.8.7 for Mac (the latest Mac-version)?